# JQuery Multi Select Box trigger/detect "unselect"

Tags: jquery, select, detect, box

I have been struggling here for days.

I have a multi select box, I want to trigger when an item of the box has been deselected.

e.g. Box with 10 items.
Items 1 to 8 are selected by default.

User deselect using "Ctr + Left Mouse Click" item 4.

How do I know item 4 was clicked/deselected?
Is this possible?

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#multipleSelect').on("change", function() {
    var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried $("#selectedfunction").on("change", function ? or $("#selectedfunction").change(

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work for me.
I used sofar this.
 $("#selectedfunction").click(function(e) {
               $.each($(this).val(), function( index, value ) {
        alert( index + ": " + value );
        
      });

But this gave me all selected items. -__-

Comment: Ok this one works but the box says: "undefined" 

 $("#selectedfunction").change(function(e) {
       alert(  $('#multipleSelect').val() ); 
    });